# Setting different XML tags with one command

Tags: android, xml, textview

Is there a way to set text color, background. For example can i create my own textview with predefined text color and background?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a style in styles.xml and define all the required parameters. Then you can simply set the style and get everything done with a single line

```
<style name="myText" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">    
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>     
    <item name="android:textColor">#333</item>    
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>   
</style>
```

and the apply this text using

```
textView.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.myText);
```